# Mudar o zoom do site com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Tem algum plugin que deixa o site do tamanho da tela? Quando um site abre na resolução `x`, ele fica daquele tamanho. Por exemplo, quando abro o site na TV ele fica pequeno e quero que ele aumente de tamanho.

Fiz um exemplo do que seria:

```
<script>
$( window ).resize(function() {
 h = $( window ).height();

 if(h >= 900){
     $('body').css("zoom", "150%");
 }

 if(h <= 899){
     $('body').css("zoom", "100%");
 }

 if(h <= 425){
     $('body').css("zoom", "50%");
 }

});
$(document).ready(function() {
 h = $( window ).height();

 if(h >= 900){
     $('body').css("zoom", "150%");
 }

 if(h <= 899){
     $('body').css("zoom", "100%");
 }

 if(h <= 425){
     $('body').css("zoom", "50%");
 }

});
</script>
```

Se não for um plugin, como deixar esse código funcional?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor " deixa o site do tamanho da tela " ? como assim? fazer o site expandir para usar o ecrã inteiro?

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar media queries em vez de javascript?

Comment: tipo quando abre o site na resolução x ele fica daquele tamanho, tipo quando abro o site na tv ele fica pequeno e quero que ele aumente de tamanho...

Comment: Acho que precisa somente de CSS. Media queries.

Comment: Quer que o conteúdo seja sempre o maximo possivel ou quer defenir `n` tamanhos diferentes?

Comment: tem que ser um tamanho que respeite as margens e talz...

Comment: Acho que o que você está querendo não tem como fazer, o site na TV não fica estendido por causa da resolução. Isso vai ter que ser feito com CSS como @Sergio disse

Answer (score 4):

Você pode desenvolver com css:

Na imagens você pode usar o `Cover`:

```
 background: url(imagem_cover.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Já no layout tem o `@media` para diferente layout como tablet, celular e ate página de impressão.

Exemplo:

```
 @media (min-width: 700px){
   css..
 }
```

Mais informação:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score -4):

Redireciona de acordo com a resolução

O javascript vai fica assim:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  if (screen.width == 800 || screen.height == 600)
    window.location.replace("800600/index.php")

  else if (screen.width == 640 || screen.height == 480)
    window.location.replace("640480/index.php")

  else if (screen.width == 1024 || screen.height == 768)
    window.location.replace("1240768/index.php")

  else
    window.location.replace("1240768/index.php ")
</script>

o css fica assim:

<style>
  body {
    zoom: nivel;
    -moz-transform: scale(nivel);
  }
</style>
```

O css fica assim:

```
<style>
  body {
    zoom: nivel;
    -moz-transform: scale(nivel);
  }
</style>
```

Onde tem nível é a escala de ampliação, ai e só testar qual se adéqua melhor em cada resolução e redirecione com o código javascript.